# Найти элементы, которые больше всех предыдущих элементов

Tags: python

Всем привет, есть задание "Найти элементы, которые больше всех предыдущих элементов списка), никак не могу допереть как обращаться сразу ко всем предыдущим элементам, а не к одному. Подскажите как можно решить это задание.

```
import random

newlist = []
testlist = []
a=1
b=300

def list_create():
    for i in range(1, 30):
        newlist.append(random.randint(a,b))

    print(newlist)

list_create()
```

Comment: Привидите пример данных

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import random

newlist = []
testlist = []
a=1
b=300

def list_create():
    for i in range(1, 30):
        newlist.append(random.randint(a,b))

    return newlist

list_ = list_create()
for i in range(1, len(list_)):
    if max(list_[:i]) < list_[i]:
        print(list_[i])
```

с помощью `list_[:x]` перем все предыдущие элементы и находим максимум

---

более эффективный вариант

```
import random

newlist = []
testlist = []
a=1
b=300

def list_create():
    for i in range(1, 30):
        newlist.append(random.randint(a,b))

    return newlist

list_ = list_create()
max_ = list_[0]
for el in list_[1:]:
    if max_ < el:
        print(el)
        max_ = el
```

Comment: все хорошо, но O(n^2) все таки :)

Comment: Спасибо, именно то, что и нужно!) Прочитал про срезы, оказывается все намного проще, чем кажется.

Comment: Нет необходимости брать все предыдыщие элементы. Если у вас список на 100500 значений, так и будете каждый раз искать максимум среди 100300 элементов?

Answer (score 3):

Вообще не нужно обращаться ко всем предыдущим элементам, достаточно хранить одно число - максимальный элемент из предыдущих.

Answer (score 3):

1. идите по массиву слева направо
2. определяйте максимальный элемент
3. если максимальный элемент - это текущий элемент, выводите элемент как максимальный из текущих

но вы должны понимать, что в последовательности `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7` будет выводиться `2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7`

но это соответствует вашему условию

> которые больше всех предыдущих элементов